# Installing SharePoint 2013 error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When running New-SPConfigurationDatabase I get the following error:

> cmdlet New-SPConfigurationDatabase at command pipeline position 1
>   Supply values for the following parameters: FarmCredentials
>   Passphrase: ***************** New-SPConfigurationDatabase : The
>   service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it
>   has no enabled devices associated with it. At line:1 char:1
>   + New-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseName DEV_SharePoint_Config
>   -DatabaseServer  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...urationDatabase:
>   SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase) [New-SPConfigurationDatabase],
>   COMExce   ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPCon    figurationDatabase

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,  Bob

Comment: what is your command, could you please share with masking the name...

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.  I had run a script to install the latest CU and it had set some services to disabled and did not set them back to automatic.  Thanks for looking at this issue for me.